# how to enable interactivity on named map in cartodb

Tags: carto, carto-js

I have created a named map that gets data from a private table.  I can load it into a Leaflet map and can change its marker-fill color placeholder using layer.setParams.

However, I cannot get interactivity to work.  I want to be able to hover or click on a feature and do something useful.[1]

What do I need to do to make hover or click events fire?

Here is the named map json file

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "mynamedmap",
  "auth": {
   "method": "open" 
  },
  "placeholders": {
      "color": {
        "type":"css_color",
        "default":"blue"
      }
  },
  "layergroup": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "layers": [{
      "type": "cartodb",
      "options": {
        "cartocss_version": "2.1.1", 
        "cartocss": "#layer { marker-fill: <%= color %>; }",
        "sql": "select * from mytable",
        "interactivity": ["cartodb_id"]
      }
    }]
  } 
}
```

Here is the javascript to create the layer:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
        type: 'namedmap',
        user_name: 'myusername',
        options: {
          named_map: {
            name: 'myusername@mynamedmap'
          }
}})            
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer) {
    console.log(layer.getSubLayerCount()); //prints '0'        
    layer.setParams('color', 'green'); // works to change marker color

    layer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
      console.log(e, latlng, pos, data); //this never gets called
    });

  });
```

[1] "Something useful" could be as simple as open infowindow and display cartodb_id and feature name.  Or it could mean "get cartodb_id for feature, pass it to my proxy where I can use curl to run some custom sql against my private table, then return json to the map and update display"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel a bit of an idiot for not figuring this out sooner.  Here is the solution that worked for me.

Add the following line to the namedmap definition:
`layers: [{}]`

The call to createLayer then looks like this:

```
cartodb.createLayer(this.map.baseMap, {
      type: 'namedmap',
      user_name: 'myusername',
      options: {
        named_map: {
          name: namedMap.name,
          layers: [{}]
})
.done(function (layer) {
  var subLayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
  subLayer.setInteraction(true);

});
```

After doing so, you can add event handling like:

```
      subLayer.on('featureOver', function(e, latlon, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
        console.log("hovered over");
        console.log(data);
      });
```

It would have been very helpful for me, as I have commented in another post on this forum, for more thorough documentation - a response there indicated that it is coming, which is great news, as CartoDb is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing enabling interaction. Try this:

```
layer.getSubLayer(0).setInteraction(true);
layer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
    console.log(e, latlng, pos, data); //this never gets called
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is certainly what works in cases where there are sublayers.  However, it appears that sublayers do not exist when using named maps.  As I mentioned in my post, `getSubLayerCount()` returns 0.  I will post an answer shortly with my workaround, which is UTFGrid.  I really would love a cartodb-native solution, though, as UTFGrid is a little clunky for my needs

Comment: Update - you were correct, although the answer was incomplete.  It was my fault for failing to have sublayers as part of the named map layer definition, and I didn't realize that until now.  The real problem was with a lack of subLayers, not so much with interaction, per se.  I've upvoted your answer but selected my own as the correct one.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise of that! Thank you for the information. [CartoDB documentation](https://github.com/CartoDB/docs) is updated every day, and including every case possible is hard, but I also feel named maps documentation lacks some tips. Working on it, any suggestion is appreciated :)

Comment: How does one choose which fields are queried on 'featureClick" ? using setInteractivity('fieldName') returns an error

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this was my original answer before I actually solved my problem*

In case anyone is having this problem - I haven't figured out how to do this using just cartodb.js, but my workaround is to use the [UTFGrid Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.utfgrid).  It's pretty simple to use.  My main gripe is that when you change the parameters of the named map (by calling `setParams()`), the UTFGrid data becomes out of sync with the new features that are displayed.  This isn't a problem with UTFGrid, per se.

This means you need to make another call to generate a new UTFGrid after you call `setParams()`.  In case you're interested:  in order to generate a new UTFGrid, you must get the updated layergroupid of the original CartoDB layer.  This changes whenever you call `setParams`.  It isn't updated until the resulting call to the server after `setParams` has returned.  However, because there isn't (as far as I can tell) any way to tell when `layer.setParams()` has completed, I have resorted to using `setTimeout` to wait a little while.  On the timeout, I can grab `layer.layerToken` and generate a new UTFGrid.  Kind of kludgy.

This is the best I've come up with for now - please post a better answer if you have one!  I really would like to be able to do this without the workaround.  Seems like it *should* work natively through just CartoDb...if anyone more familiar with that wants to weigh in, please do.