# Add marker interactivity to a carto map

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

I've got a working example of a map that adds a marker layer with the `creatLayer` method. I am trying to add a click listener to the carto markers. I have tried the examples [here](https://carto.com/docs/tutorials/custom_interactivity/) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127853/how-to-enable-interactivity-on-named-map-in-cartodb) to no avail.

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/whayler1/db4e5bf8d50a45872ed1fd969fd3a6c6) is where I am at right now. You'll see the markers are loading, but no interaction on click (it should call an alert). I have tried a lot of variations on the click listener code at this point.

Code pasted below as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>How to add markers to a CARTO map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }  
</style>
<!-- include cartodb.js CSS library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
 <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  function main() {
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: [40.7328,-74.0059],
      zoom: 14
    });
    // var layer = L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/fluffywolf24/cimhxr71f0021qxno7nts1d4w', { detectRetina: true });
    // layer.addTo(map);
    // console.log('map:', map);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'OpenStreetMaps'
    }).addTo(map);
    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'whayler1',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
        sql: "SELECT * FROM ny_listings",
        cartocss: '#layer{marker-fill-opacity: 0.7; marker-line-color: #B40903; marker-line-width: 1; marker-line-opacity: 0; marker-placement: point; marker-type: ellipse; marker-width: 1; marker-fill: #F11810; marker-allow-overlap: true; } #layer::point{marker-fill-opacity: 0.4; marker-line-color: #B40903; marker-line-width: 1; marker-line-opacity: 1; marker-placement: point; marker-type: ellipse; marker-width: 7; marker-fill: #F11810; marker-allow-overlap: true; }'}]
    })
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
      console.log('done', layer);
      layer.setInteraction(true);
      layer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlon, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
        alert("clicked marker!");
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an interactivity line to your sublayer definition that exposes at least one column from your dataset:

```
sublayers: [{
        sql: 'SELECT * FROM ny_listings',
        cartocss: '...',
        interactivity: "cartodb_id,address"
      }]
```